# encontrar el elemento repetido en dos array

Tags: javascript

Cordial saludo. Me pueden brindar una mano porque no se me agregan a la array creada los elementos en común, que característica es la que estoy omitiendo para que me. aqui dejo el código que llevo.

```
function actividadesEnComun(persona1, persona2) {
  // La funcion llamada 'actividadesEnComun' recibe como argumento dos arrays de actividades (strings) llamados 'persona1' y 'persona2'
  // y debe devolver un array de strings con las actividades en comun ( aquellas que se repiten ) entre cada array.
  // ej: persona1 = ['leer', 'comer', 'pasear', 'dormir', 'jugar']
  //     persona2 = ['comer', 'dormir', 'futbol']
  // actividadesEnComun(persona1, persona2) => ['comer', 'dormir']
  // Tip: podes usar ciclos for anidados.
  // Tu código aca:

  
  var nuevaarray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < persona1.length; i++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < persona2.length; i++) {
    if(persona2[i] === persona1[i]){
      nuevaarray.push(persona2[i]);

       }

     }
  }

return nuevaarray;

}
```

Comment: Las dos variables que tienen los índices las nombraste como `i`, prueba utilizar distintos alias. De todas maneras prueba aplicando `filters` e `includes` para la solución ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo mi propuesta, usando `forEach` para recorrer ***persona1*** y usando una función para determinar si el elemento enviado existe o no en ***persona2*** por medio de `includes`, sí existe lo guardó en ***coincidencias***, quedaría así:

```js
let persona1 = ['leer', 'comer', 'pasear', 'dormir', 'jugar'];
let persona2 = ['comer', 'dormir', 'futbol'];
let coincidencias = [];

persona1.forEach(comparar);

function comparar(item) {
  if(persona2.includes(item) && (coincidencias.includes(item) === false)){
  coincidencias.push(item);
  };
}

console.log(coincidencias);
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar el objecto Set de ES06

```js
function intersect(a, b) {
      return a.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(b));
    }
    
console.log(intersect([1,2,3], [2,3,4,5])); // [2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

En el for anidado debes usar un for of, tal cual de la siguiente manera:

```
function buscarAmigos (persona1,persona2) {

var coincidencias=[];

  for(var k=0; k<persona1.length; k++) {

    for(var elemento of persona2) {
      if(persona1[k] === elemento ) {
       coincidencias.push(elemento);
     }
   }
  }
  return coincidencias;
}
```